# Latest version of Wokrbench requires old Mysql version when trying to export a DB, but couldn't downgrade Mysql (Wampserver) (with error screenshot)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try to export a DB in workbench, it tells me error as in the screenshot below: [image]

As I understood, it wants me to downgrade MySQL, which is currently v5.7.19 came with the wampserver. But when I went to wampserver website I didn't find such MySQL version in older wampserver versions.

Also, when I check updates fro workbench, I am told it is latest version.

If the solution to this problem not by going that way, Please tell me.
In all cases, please help me to solve the problem showed in the screenshot.

Comment: Vereions `5.7.17` and `5.7.19` look very close to each other, probably within a few months.  You could try finding the differences, which may not affect your export, in which case you could just click "Continue Anyway."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error, but a generic warning Workbench shows when the server is newer than the tools it ships with. This is to let you know that some new features *may* not be supported. In this particular case the difference should be minimal and you can ignore the message. Alternatively, you can point MySQL Workbench to the mysqldump binary of the current server (using the application settings).